# Simplifying $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k+1} - 1$ into the form of $-2^{-k - 1} (2^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to get $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{k+1} - 1$ into the form of $-2^{-k - 1} (2^{k + 1} - 3^{k + 1})$.

Using the power of a fraction rule I am up to:

$\frac{3^{k + 1}}{2^{k +1}} - 1$

But I am stuck on the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step is to write this fraction-minus-$1$ as$$\frac{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}=2^{-k-1}(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})=-2^{-k-1}(2^{k+1}-3^{k+1}).$$